# Error while converting string to SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Here is my C# code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //login button
  SqlConnection sqlConn = "Your Conncetion String"; //The error is here
  sqlConn.Open();

  SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
  sqlComm.CommandText = String.Format("select * from users where userName=@userName and password=@password");
  sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
  sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
  sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  sqlComm.Connection = sqlConn;
  SqlDataReader sqlRead = sqlComm.ExecuteReader();
  if (sqlRead.Read())
  {
    Session["username"] = sqlRead["username"];
  }

  // SqlRead.Close();

  //sqlConn1.Close();

  Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");

}
```

Can someone explain what this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Well you need to show your code!

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: ***Show Code*** (vtc)

Comment: The error message could not be more clear. In what way do you not understand it?

Comment: it should be `SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Your Conncetion String")`

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: @GregB the second one...

Answer (score 5):

I understand you have a connection string and want a `SqlConnection` object. You can use one of its constructors:

```
string connString = "Your Conncetion String"; // valid connection string
var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
```

It will be best if you use `using` keyword as this will take care of closing the connection properly. You should also use `using` for your `SqlReader`.

```
using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    sqlConn.Open();
    // the rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change**

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = "Your Conncetion String";
```

**To**

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Your Conncetion String");
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Your Conncetion String");
```

You can read it from web.config

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new  
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
```

---

> now this error The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context

1. You have to add a reference to the `System.Configuration.dll`
2. then add `using System.Configuration;` to your class.
3. You can now access your config file like this:

   `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.

Comment: now this error 
The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context